# Azure Machine Learning Studio - Input port Dataset is unconnected

Tags: web-services, azure, machine-learning

[image: My error]

I want to get the input file as a web service input. But it says gives the error "Input port dataset is unconnected". I want to take the input file from the user and send the model results back to ASP.NET web page. Please help on how to do that. Above is the screenshot of the experiment